# How to show the election history page when there is an ongoing election?

Tags: support, election

Viewing the /election page on a site where there is currently no election, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/election/ shows a list of past elections:

[image: election history]

However, the same page on a site where there is an ongoing election, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/election/ shows the current election:

[image: ongoing election]

Is there any URL which displays the entire election history for Mathematics right now? I'm aware of the links to single past elections, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, there is no such way on the site itself; you'll have to rely on external sources like the Wayback Machine ([example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507015803/https://math.stackexchange.com/election/)). Note that most of the snapshots are made when there is an active election.

It *used* to be possible to get to the election history by just adding a number <s>higher than the number of elections</s> of a non-existing election to the URL, e.g.:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9
- https://math.stackexchange.com/election/0
- https://math.stackexchange.com/election/-1 even works.

<sub>(thanks @JonClements)</sub>

[image: election history]

Comment: Too bad https://math.stackexchange.com/election/all doesn't work, would be more intuitive.

Comment: None of those workarounds works with the currently running election on Math.SE. (The first link “works” because that *is* the current election :)

Comment: @MartinR right. They somehow fixed the 'bug', so I've updated the answer to include an off-site resource which *might* work.

Comment: Great, thanks. – It would still be nice to have an official URL for that purpose, such as the `election/all` suggested above.