# Allow me to open the full list of all elections on a site during an active election

Tags: feature-request, election

According to the Q&A [How to show the election history page when there is an ongoing election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301637/339911), it's not possible to open the table listing all elections on the site when an election is ongoing on the site.

I'm asking to allow that somehow without using external resources like Wayback Machine.

That page could be usable to compare the outcome from the past elections.

Comment: This used to be possible by changing the election URL to a nonexistent election number, but doing that now (correctly) leads to a 404 error.